# SurfaceListBox not responding to touch gestures for several seconds

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, touch, windowsformshost

I have a WPF-program that has a grid with two columns. First one has buttons and second one has `WindowsFormsHost`-element that embeds an ActiveX component. One button hides the `WindowsFormsHost`-element and shows a `SurfaceListBox` on the same location on screen in the second column. If I have touched the `WindowsFormsHost` element just before pressing this button, it takes approximately 8 seconds from the last touch until the `SurfaceListBox` becomes responsible for touch gestures.

The thread is probably not blocked, because I can use the buttons in another column, and use use the `ListBox` with mouse.

The `ListBox` remains unresponsive for touch events forever, if I touch it within the 8 second waiting time. So it seems that somehow the `ListBox` does not get the touch events.

If I programmatically create another `ListBox`, it does not work either, for 8 seconds, if it is placed in same are on screen than the `WindowsFormsHost` was.

I noticed there is a method `CaptureTouch()` for `UIElement`, but I cannot get hold of to the `TouchDevice` that I could pass it as parameter. I have set `ManipulationEnabled="true"` for every `UIElement` and no `TouchEvent` will be fired.

I have also desperately used `UpdateLayout()` etc with no luck.

So I think the touch gestures are somehow routed wrong and after the waiting time it implicitly fixes the routing, but is there a way I could make the touch gestures work in the `ListBox` immediately?

Comment: Hi welcome to SO, could you please read through [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? Include relevant code, xaml and information, and it's better chances of getting good answers and upvotes :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem disappeared when I removed "focus tracking for launching on-screen keyboard" from my program.

So in case of somebody else struggles with the same problem, 
http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/blagunas/archive/2013/12/17/showing-the-windows-8-touch-keyboard-in-wpf.aspx and SurfaceListBoxes aren't meant for each other.